# Resize view when UINavigationBar is hidden

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want the view of my current UIViewController to take the whole screen (without the status bar) when I hide the UINavigationBar. It doesn't have to be animated. I can't figure out how to change the frames. I should mention also that I am using a nib, so in the Interface Builder  I have selected Simulated Metrics : Navigation Bar, I don't know if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// On YourViewController.m

// Call this method when the nav bar gets hidden
- (void)navigationBarDidBecomeHidden {
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
}
```